# Getting CMHeadphoneMotionManager info on MacOS

Tags: macos, core-motion

There are plenty of resources that allow to use CoreMotion, and in particular CMHeadphoneMotionManager on iOS, which is not the case on MacOS.

I have read [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/129351) that "Macs don’t support CoreMotion.  The framework is present in the macOS SDK for the benefit of Mac Catalyst but much of the API is marked as unavailable and those bits that you can call won’t return useful info".

An attempt to solve these issues is provided through a python wrapper in the [pyobjc](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc) library, but the class I'm interested in is not implemented (CMHeadphoneMotionManager).

I need to get the airpods pro orientation directly to macos, while also sending audio back to them (i.e. not possible to use an iOS app doing the job in parallel, as Airpods can only connect to one device at a time).